# Grap all text after given word

Tags: python, c#, regex

I would like to grap all text after given keyword

```
Slot ID = 10, Machine type = 2000, Comments, FileName, Image Orientation = DecToSource, Background = 0, Center_X = 0, Center_Y = 0, OI = -1, AT angle = 0, Location X = 15.878, Location Y = 21.26
Slot ID A, Machine type = 2000, Comments, FileName, Image Orientation = DecToSource, Background = 0, Center_X = 0, Center_Y = 0, OI = 0.9, AT angle = 0, Location X
```

This example. if I give "Slot ID" my expectation is grab

"**10**, Machine type = 2000, Comments, FileName, Image Orientation = DecTo## Heading ##Source, Background = 0, Center_X = 0, Center_Y = 0, OI = -1, AT angle = 0, Location X = 15.878, Location Y = 21.26"

"**A,** Machine type = 2000, Comments, FileName, Image Orientation = DecToSource, Background = 0, Center_X = 0, Center_Y = 0, OI = -1, AT angle = 0, Location X = 15.878, Location Y = 21.26"

I tried with below expression, but this is always not able to grab "Slot ID =" case.

**`(?<=((Slot ID )|(Slot ID = ))).`**

Which point was wrong ?

Comment: In what language? You've tagged both Python and C#.

Comment: [python], [c#], and [nsregularexpression] don't mix. Please only use the relevant tags.

Comment: The safest option that would work with almost all regex flavors is `^Slot ID (?:= )?(.+)$` where the expected match will be in the first capturing group. Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cCZGvl/1

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do the trick:

```
^(?:Slot\sID\s(?:=\s)?\s*)(.*)$
```

The first is a non-capturing group, then it captures everything else after the comma (and optional spaces) till the end `$`.

Using `^` in the start requires that the matching group is the first one, if this is not your case, try swapping the first `^` with `.*`.

(More info: https://regexr.com/58hnr )

Comment: Why the `[^,]*,\s*` part? OP seems to want to include whatever is before the first comma in the match. Also (nitpicking), the non-capturing group is unnecessary and the first capturing group should be non-capturing.

Comment: My bad, I read the text too quickly. Thank you for pointing that out, I fixed the first part as you mentioned. For the second part, you mean that `(=\s)` is capturing? Now it is non-capturing as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use string.split method?

```
string text = "Slot ID = 10, Machine type = 2000, Comments, FileName, Image Orientation = DecToSource, Background = 0, Center_X = 0, Center_Y = 0, OI = -1, AT angle = 0, Location X = 15.878, Location Y = 21.26";

string[] array =  text.Split("Slot ID = ");
```